# stay in the current page after clicking cancel button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp, alert

I have a form in index.jsp and after clicking submit i am showing an alert "confirm submit?" if *ok* will be clicked then confirmsubmit.jsp will be displayed. I am getting text box name in  confirmsubmit.jsp by `request.getParameter("textboxname");`But problem is if I click *cancel* then also confirmsubmit.jsp is opening, how can I stay in index.jsp after clicking cancel button in alert?

Any help please

index.jsp

```
<form action="confirmsubmit.jsp" method="POST">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function confirmation() {
var answer = confirm("Confirm submit?")
if (answer){

    window.location = "confirmsubmit.jsp";// goes to confirmsubmit.jsp
}
else{
    //should remain in index.jsp but here also confirmsubmit.jsp is opening
}
}
//-->
</script>
<input type="text" name="textboxname"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="confirmation()"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: Add return with confirmation() method i.e <input type="submit" onclick="return confirmation()"/>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add following line in the else part:

```
return false;
```

and change your `onclick` to:

```
return confirmation();
```

=== UPDATE ===

Because you have the `confirmsubmit.jsp` in the form action, you don't need the `window.location`:

```
function confirmation() {
    if (!confirm("Confirm submit?")) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/2xnM2/).

Comment: thanks scessor for quick answer but i am still able to view `confirmsubmit.jsp` after clicking cancel button

Comment: The result must be returnd from the onclick too.

Comment: yeah it worked thanks a lot scessor, we met after a long time

Comment: I've added a shorter solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <form action="confirmsubmit.jsp" method="POST">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function confirmation() {
    var answer = confirm("Confirm submit?")
    if (answer){

        window.location = "confirmsubmit.jsp";// goes to confirmsubmit.jsp
        return true;
    }
    else{
        //should remain in index.jsp but here also confirmsubmit.jsp is opening
    return false;
    }
    }
    //-->
    </script>
    <input type="text" name="textboxname"/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="return confirmation()"/> 

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take off `return` from `onclick` and add `return false;` if `!answer`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmation() {
    var answer = confirm("Confirm submit?")
    if (!answer){
        return false;
    }
}
</script>

<form action="confirmsubmit.jsp" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="textboxname"/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="confirmation()"/> 
</form>
```